# Is 64-bit background geoprocessing native to ArcGIS 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, 64bit, geoprocessing-framework, background-geoprocessing

I cannot seem to find any documentation as to whether or not 64-bit background geoprocessing is native to ArcGIS 10.2.  Or, is a separate download and install required as in 10.1?  There were rumors prior to the 10.2 release that 64-bit background geoprocessing comes pre-installed with the upgrade/download.  Is there an authoritative reference on this subject?  No relevant system information is available on my Arc Administrator configuration information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an option in the **ArcGIS 10.2 Desktop Install** for 64bit background Geo-Processing.

[image]

Comment: Note: This might of been missed if your IT Department installs ArcGIS for you.

Comment: Would the 64-bit geoprocessing show up on Arc Administrator if it were active?  Or, what is the best method to confirm its existence?

Comment: See Using geoprocessing options to control tool execution http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00210000000q000000 as has an option for "Execute in the background or foreground"

Comment: If it's like the same addon in 10.1, it will also show up as its own entry in Control Panel > Programs and Features.

Comment: I am pretty sure background geoprocessing can exist without the 64-bit download.

Comment: You can also check for the existence of C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.2

Answer (score 4):

In response to the answer which suggests to turn off background geoprocessing, I will just mention that if you do this you will negate the very purpose of the 64-Bit Geoprocessing installation.  In order to take advantage of the 64-bit capability that this installation offers, you MUST have background geoprocessing turned on.  Here are a few quotes (with sources) to back this up:

- *You can check the General tab of the tool properties for the Always run in foreground check box to see if a tool is capable of running in
  the background.* Source:
  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002100000040000000
- *To use 64-bit Geoprocessing make sure Background Processing is enabled in the Geoprocessing Options. As long as a tool is capable of
  running in the background, it will leverage 64-bit processing.*
  Source: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/10/31/announcing-64-bit-geoprocessing/

Comment: +1. Welcome to our site! (Although this is only an indirect response to the question, I think it's fair to construe the links as addressing the request for references and I agree with the person who commented that overall this is a "quality response.")

Answer (score -1):

Also, if you are running ArcGIS under 8.1 (not yet officially supported, but it runs), you may want to TURN OFF background geoprocessing as it throws exceptions running tools that work fine when it is turned off.  Don't know whether this is an artifact of some as yet unresolved incompatibility with 8.1 that will be fixed down the road.

Comment: Did you mean Windows 8.1?

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem but did not have the installation setup program that provided me with the screenshot attached in the first answer.  Here is a [link to the 10.1 service pack 1](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/1913#choose-product) that has the option, but I don't know whether this will cause problems when installing on 10.2.

Comment: I have not tried this but I suspect that it would cause problems.