# Installing 64-bit geoprocessing of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, arcgis-10.2, 64bit, geoprocessing-framework

I am trying to install 64-bit processing to ArcGIS 10.2, but the ESRI [Patches and Service Packs website only has installations for Service pack 1 that goes with ArcGIS 10.1](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/1913#choose-product).

One similar question on this exchange [shows a screenshot of an installation window](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80459/is-64-bit-background-geoprocessing-native-to-arcgis-10-2) that shows an option to include this, but my setup installation program (which I downloaded) does not show this installation window, but instead goes straight to selecting features to install as shown below.

I can't find any other documentation for running 64-bit geoprocessing on ArcGIS version 10.2.  Can anyone show me how to do this? or is it best to just try to install the service pack 1 version of it?

[image]

Comment: While I'm not a customer (I'm an employee), so I dont have access to the site - it was my understanding that at 10.2 the 64bit background setup was available in the same location you downloaded 10.2 Desktop from. I believe thats customers.esri.com, not from the patches/support site.

Answer (score 11):

If you launch the autorun.exe application, it will launch the startup window (otherwise known as the Quick Start Guide) of the 10.2 installation for Desktop.  The option you're looking for is the 2nd one down from the ArcGIS for Desktop header:

[image]

**Note:** After some reading through the Esri forums, it appears that the 10.2 64-bit Background Geoprocessing installation is not included with a trial or student version of ArcGIS for Desktop.

**You should be able to download the full install, subject to your eligibility, from [My Esri](https://my.esri.com/welcome).**

Comment: I don't have such a file on my computer, nor do I have a Quick Start Guide.  I've searched the entire computer for both names. I am using the ArcGIS for Desktop Student Trial, which I downloaded and does not appear to come with this setup guide.

Comment: After some reading through the Esri forums, it appears that the 10.2 64-bit Background Geoprocessing installation is not included with a trial or student version of ArcGIS for Desktop.  That being said, I think the 10.2.1 service pack and patch site (once it's available) may have a download for it.  The 10.2.1 release is scheduled for end of 2013 so it should be any day now.

Comment: And today the 10.2.1 sp hit my email. It looks just like this. It is the only way you can install. Run Esri.exe

Answer (score 10):

This all depends on what **python version** your are running:

If you install on a 64 bit Operating System you will get the option.

> Since ArcGIS for Server 10.1 was released, the ArcPy library has been
>   accessible through a 64-bit platform. In addition, the 64-bit
>   Background Geoprocessing patch was released at 10.1 Service Pack 1,
>   which allows ArcGIS for Desktop users to utilize geoprocessing in
>   64-bit. This means that if you have ArcGIS for Desktop and either
>   ArcGIS for Server or the Background 64-bit Geoprocessing Patch
>   installed, you have two different installs of Python 2.7.

The default paths for those are:

C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2 – (32-bit)

**C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.2** – (64-bit)

**Background Geoprocessing (64-bit) is available as a separate installation on top of ArcGIS for Desktop. The following information only applies if you have the Background Geoprocessing (64-bit) product installed; otherwise, background processing is done in 32 bit.**

What is 64-bit Background Geoprocessing?

> The installation of the ArcGIS for Desktop—Background Geoprocessing
>   (64-bit) product replaces the regular 32-bit background processing
>   which comes standard with ArcGIS for Desktop. Using 64-bit processing
>   to perform analysis on systems with large amounts of RAM may help when
>   processing large data which may have otherwise failed in a 32-bit
>   environment. Since all execution is done in the native 64-bit space,
>   more system resources can be used.
>
> Tools that execute in the background honor your current license. For
>   example, if you are licensed for ArcGIS for Desktop Standard, then
>   background execution will honor all tools that are licensed for
>   Standard. Background processing does not consume a second license;
>   only one license per machine is used.

**If you want to return to 32-bit background processing, you need to uninstall the 64-bit background processing software.**

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002100000040000000

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/07/29/64-bit-vs-32-bit-python-explained/