# Creating tile packages (.tpk files) in ArcGIS for Desktop using multiple cores?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, performance

It takes hours or days to create tile package files on my workstation, which has 4 cores, 32G ram and a SSD drive. I noticed only one core is in active use while it is working.

Is there a way to tell ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop to use multiple cores?

Also, it would be nice to see what's going on - a preview panel would be nice? Is there any way to keep an eye on what is going on?

Comment: This tool only uses 1 core. No way to make it use multiple cores.

Comment: Also, ArcMap is still only 32-bit, so it doesn't have access to all that RAM.

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#/ArcGIS_10_1_for_Desktop/015100000002000000/

Comment: related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81066/arcgis-10-2-installation-for-64-bit-geoprocessing

Comment: Ok thanks. (Still hard to believe that in 2014 this is still single core; the process is dying to be moved to a 15-core intel box).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Manage Tile Cache tool to create a tpk, instead of File > Share as > Tile Package. This tool not only uses multiple cores, but provides other options, such as generating tiles only within area of interest features and options to cache at a broader range of scales and at specified scales.

http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001700000189000000

The tool doesn't bill itself as a way to create a tile package, nor does the help specifically describe using it for this purpose. Nevertheless, just select "RECREATE_ALL_TILES" for the Manage Mode, and it will quickly build you a tile package from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

There is an existing **[ArcGIS Idea to have Tile Packaging always use multiple cores](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004qGDIAY)**.

I recommend that you, and anyone else looking for this to be implemented, add your vote there.

Answer (score 0):

With the single core limitation, caching with ArcGIS for Desktop is only intended for cache with limited extend and/or level, such as a local government and study area.  For more exhaustive cache (e.g. North America from L0 to L18), ArcGIS for Server is the recommended approach.

In regards to monitor the process, beside keeping an eye on the created files' date in Windows Explorer, you can also use the [Status.gdb](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000005m6000000) to get addtional feedback on your caching progress.  Please note that you won't be able to see this file geodatabase inside ArcMap/ArcCatalog unless you copy it to a location other then the cache folder.  More specifically:

> Spatial information about the completion of map cache tiles is
>   contained in the Status.gdb file geodatabase in each cache folder. You
>   can make a copy of this geodatabase in another directory and open its
>   feature classes in ArcMap to see tables and maps of map cache
>   completion status. The TaskStatus feature class is especially useful
>   for seeing the tile bundle boundaries.