# Arcpy 64 bit, or multiple Python installs?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcrest

I am new to Python, and am trying to write a script that would upload a geodatabase to AGOL at a scheduled interval. However, the 32 bit distribution of Python cannot handle the file size (over 1 MB), even when the multipart parameter of addItem (using ArcREST) is set to true. Through some investigation, I've learned that this is a limitation of Python32, and to do what I'd like to do I need the 64 bit version. I was trying to avoid having multiple installs of Python (as I said, I'm new to it, so the less complication, the better), but if I remove Python as it was installed with ArcGIS, I lose Arcpy, which I also need. So, my question is, does anyone know of a solution to this issue, or am I stuck dealing with multiple Python installs?

Comment: A point on your 1MB file size: Python can certainly handle more than 1MB. I've done at least 250MB uploads to ArcGIS.com using singlepart before without any problems. Not sure what you're seeing?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81066/arcgis-10-2-installation-for-64-bit-geoprocessing/82092#82092